# Excel Conditional Formatting if 2 values in column A are equal, but their corresponding values in column B do not equal

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to find a way to highlight cells based on conditions, where if 2 values are equal in column A and their corresponding values in column B are not equal, then I would like to highlight both cells A and B (name and age) of both.

So, I want to highlight the Name and Age if the Names are Equal, but the ages are not. In the example below I would highlight Bob, 30 - Bob, 22 - Mike, 21, and Mike, 38 (because there is at least one person with the same name in column A, but that person does not have the same age).

Ex.

```
Name      Age
Bob       30
John      47
Mike      21
Sam       55
Bob       22
John      47
Mike      38
Chris     18
```

Is there a type of conditional formatting formula (or other method), that would allow me to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You would use this formula:

```
=COUNTIF($A:$A,$A2) <> COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A2,$B:$B,$B2)
```

[image]

It compares the count of the Name to the count of the names and their age.  It they are different it returns true and formats the cells.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. It is not highlighting the correct cells when I enter this equation in for the conditional formatting rule.

Comment: @Bob - What range are you using? You'll have to adjust the formula a little if it starts in like A3, B6 or wherever.

Comment: @BruceWayne I have data in cells A2 to E2 and then down about 10,000 rows. The cells of interest for me are column A (name) and Column C (Age). I changed all of the B's in the formula above to C's and it didn't work. I even tried on the sample portion I included above with the original code and it was not highlighting the correct cells.

Comment: @Bob As the rich playboy stated, make sure you adjust the formula and the Applies to: ranges to your needs.  Also make sure your data does not have unprintable extra characters like spaces.  This is looking for exact matches.  Other than that I did not photoshop the photo above.

Comment: @ScottCraner Will do, Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Bob also pay attention to what is and what is not absolute.  Make sure that The $A2 and $B2 references the first row of your data.